# Who do I call to remove old radiators

Tags: plumbing, hvac

We have an old house and we changed our heating system to a heat pump 17 years ago.  We are looking to do some remodeling and realized that we need to remove the radiators first.  We have 11 radiators throughout the house.  There is a lot of metal that could be worth something to someone.  What type of contractor should we be calling?

Comment: There are many people doing old home restoration that are always looking for vintage radiators.  You might post something on FB Marketplace or similar local forums and see if anyone is interested.  It's a shame to take such things to the scrap yard.

Comment: Be careful here, those **might** be worth a lot of money. Our church has an old style heating system in part of it that uses decorative radiators. Our boiler maint guy said that if we ever wanted to get rid of them, they could be worth a lot! Please EDIT your question to include a few pics. Then others could chime in and offer their opinions.

Comment: Do any of your neighbours have the same kind of radiators in their homes?  If so, consider gifting them the radiators if they help with removal.

Comment: Do you have a local facebook page or similar? Post a pic or 2 on there - someone may want them...

Comment: @FreshCodemonger the copper piping that will come with them is probably worth more, unless there's very little of it.

Comment: In my area there is (or was) a business that would salvage old building materials and sell them to people doing restorations.  If nothing else, they have scrap value and I would expect someone to take them of your hands at no charge.

Answer (score 18):

You call a plumber to disconnect the radiators, cap off the pipes, and if any part of the system remains in use to ensure it all still works.

The same plumber with a couple of burly assistants can move them to your driveway, or you can use your own burly assistants if you have some.

If the radiators are beautiful period pieces in good condition you look up "architectural salvage", find one within reasonable driving distance, talk to them about whether they want them and figure out if it's worth dragging them there.  Your time, your truck, your call.

If you live in an area with lots of historic homes you can ask a couple of local realtors and or the local historian (did you know you have one?  You probably do) if they know of any projects that could use these.  This is getting a bit desperate, don't expect much.

Guessing none of that works out ... you intercept the garbage truck on garbage day, hand the driver $100 and the radiators vanish. The continued presence of your burly assistants, if possible, will make the Benjy more attractive.    Note, some towns have a bulk pickup day where they'll take almost anything for free (ok, for your taxes) if you follow the rules.  If you're lucky enough to be in one of those just ask the town what the rules are.

Comment: Or ask your town what policy is for such things, which might cost you less than $100. Or call a local metal recycler. Heck, my area has folks who roam neighborhoods with a pickup looking for scrap metal being thrown out that they can turn into money; apparently if you can gather enough that does pay them enough to cover the gas and leave some income.

Comment: @keshlam good point about town policy, I added that to the answer.

Comment: PAY somebody to take them away? In my area (London, UK) scrap collectors prowl the streets and take them away for free and in some cases are willing to pay for large pieces of metal.

Comment: In the UK (and probably other places too), there are official recycling centres in many locations where you're encouraged to take any recyclable material - at no charge for local residents. Some local councils will also pick up large items for disposal from outside your home, for a small fee.

Comment: Waiting/hoping for a scrap dealer to pick them up, either for free or even to pay you, is an option you balance with how long you want a bunch of rusting hulks sitting on your lawn.  Eventually you, your neighbors, or your town's code enforcer will want them gone.  It's worth a shot at calling a scrap dealer and waiting up to a week I guess for them to come before you pay to hurry it up.  If these people are literally prowling the streets as in @j4nd3r53n's town, that's great (well, not really) but my experience is different.  Usable furniture and toys disappear quickly, nothing else.

Answer (score 9):

You have two tasks at hand:

1. Remove old radiators and presumably the piping
2. Dispose of the radiators and piping

It sounds like you're hoping that the person who takes advantage of task #2 will do task #1 for free. That is a surefire way to get someone to mess up your lovely home with stagnant and rusty water that drips from these units once they've been sawzall'd off.

Hire a plumber for task #1 and then seek a solution for task #2. You can scrap the metal yourself or just move it to the curb and a metal scrapper will gladly pick it up in short order.

If you're trying to lure a proper plumber on the premise of paying them with metal then you're disrespecting them.

---

As for:

> There is a lot of metal that could be worth something to someone.

You are more than welcome to hold on to all the metal if you wish to find a buyer or merely a second life for these units.

Comment: Yes, I think this is correct: the disconnection is a serious professional job, so hire a plumber. No, the plumber does not want to be paid in scrap metal. :)

Answer (score 4):

Call your local college or university to see if they have a cast iron sculpture program. Iron sculptors melt these down to make art. They’ll come to you and take them away at no cost. I know… I’m an iron sculptor who learned my trade at a state college in Buffalo, NY.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, installers of radiators are prepared to remove old units, and any competent company already has a decent disposal practice.  Additionally, most plumbers can do this, provided they bring assistants to help lift and move the unit.

So, call up a radiator installer, and ask them what is their going rate to have one removed.

I wouldn't hold out much hope that the metal in the radiator is worth much.  While it is heavy, good recycling rates are around 20 cents a pound, with radiators being between 40 and 150 pounds.  That's roughly between $10 and $30 dollars.  Higher value metals go for more, but this isn't high value metal (copper / stainless steel).

Consider yourself lucky if you don't need to pay them to dispose of it in exchange for the scrap value.  Odds are the costs to move it exceed the cash they get from it.

Comment: With 11 radiators in total, it's still $200-$300 in scrap value. To me that sounds like quite a lot of money, especially given that loading them all on a truck and taking them to a scrapyard won't take more than a couple person-hours.

Comment: 20 cents would be awesome.  I get less than 3 cents a pound for scrap steel.

Comment: @TooTea It takes me 30 minutes to load and unload 500 pounds of fresh water (I keep fish tanks).  I doubt that one could load and unload 4 times the weight in radiators in an hour, and drive to and from the recycling center in under an hour.  That's 2 hours, and a plumber and an assistant makes it 4 man-hours.  At $50 a man-hour, or more likely $10, the plumber isn't making their money recycling.  Like I said, they're often doing you a favor if they dispose of it for the recycling money.